# Browser fails to process alert box when swiching tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

As I know, alert(message) will display an alert box with message and a OK button, and it will stop  executing the codes after alert function until the OK button being clicked. But there is one situation that if I switch tabs from one page to another and back again, the codes after alert are executed and the alert box is still there. Is this a bug or designed so?

I have tested Firefox and IE browsers, there's no this issue, but Chrome and Edge works samely. By the way, the behavior will be different if the developer tools are open.

The examples are as follow:

When click button1 and alert box shows up, just switch to another tab and back again, value of button2 will change to "123" and the alert box is still there.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
            function fun() {
               alert (" Hello World \n This is an alert dialog box ");
               document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("value", 123);
            }
            function fun2() {
               document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("value", "Test");
            }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p> Click the following button to see the effect </p>
      <form>
         <input type = "button" name="button1" value = "Click me" onclick = "fun();" />
         <input type = "button" name="button2" id="test" value = "Test" onclick = "fun2()" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to say it is by design in order not to block the script execution. Here's a [design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wtV5rmLhbf1OZkbg7crtCt6h1mMtig_ctTQt3BLLEIU/edit#heading=h.npn9zknonl9m) for you to refer to. It says:

> However, if the user were to switch to a different tab, moving the tab
> into the background and making it not foremost, we would dismiss the
> dialog.

Comment: Yes, I also find this document today. I agree that it is designed so. One more slight difference is that the dialog does't dismiss, maybe more change has been made. Very appreciate.

Comment: @KingRumn You're welcome. They seem to have made a compromise which will both ensure the script execution and maintain the alert for users to see. BTW, do you have any update on this issue? You can share with us. Regards.